# Return to initial ViewController in view hierarchy when tab is reopened

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am currently experiencing an issue with `UITabBarController`s and `UINavigationControllers`.

Say I have 2 `ViewControllers` in my `UITabBar`:

- MenuOne
- MenuTwo

On `MenuOne` I have a button that leads to a new `ViewController`; `PageOne`.

If I navigate to the first tab (`MenuOne`) and then click the button with the push segue to `PageOne`, the Tab Bar remains. If I tap on the second tab (`MenuTwo`) and then return to `MenuOne`, I am taken back to `PageOne` which is where I left off in that view hierarchy.

My understanding is that this is Apple's intent and this is how `UITabBarControllers` work with `UINavigationControllers`, but when I'm a few ViewControllers deep in `MenuOne`, I don't want my users to be navigating through the tabs and not being redirected to the initial `ViewController`.

For clarification, this is what the process looks like now:

`MenuOne` > * **taps button** * > `PageOne` > * **taps tab** * > `MenuTwo` > * **taps tab** * > `PageOne`

And this is how I want it to work:

`MenuOne` > * **taps button** * > `PageOne` > * **taps tab** * > `MenuTwo` > * **taps tab** * > *`MenuOne`*

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `UITabBarController` like this:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.delegate = self
    }

    // when a controller is selected...
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let vc = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            // pop the navigation controller to root VC
            vc.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

In the storyboard, set the class of your `UITabBarController` to `MyTabBarController`.

Comment: Wow, surprised how easy this was. Thank you!